# Generate random datetimes in rails with the minutes belongs to range(00, 30)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, random

`Event` model which has `start` and `end` `datetime` attributes in the database. I want to seed some random events but the event time should be proper.

For example:

```
6.times { date_range << DateTime.now + (rand * 21) }
```

generates

```
[Thu, 03 Aug 2017 21:22:48 +0530,
 Tue, 08 Aug 2017 17:36:29 +0530,
 Sat, 29 Jul 2017 06:19:51 +0530,
 Sat, 29 Jul 2017 13:36:21 +0530,
 Thu, 27 Jul 2017 15:08:55 +0530,
 Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:53:03 +0530]
```

which is the correct behaviour.

But how to generate random datetime like this:

```
[Thu, 03 Aug 2017 21:00:00 +0530,
Tue, 08 Aug 2017 17:30:00 +0530,
Sat, 29 Jul 2017 06:00:00 +0530,
Sat, 29 Jul 2017 13:00:00 +0530,
Thu, 27 Jul 2017 15:30:00 +0530,
Fri, 04 Aug 2017 13:00:00 +0530]
```

So in order to display these events properly on a calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try separating out each segment and adding them onto the date individually

```
date_range = 6.times.collect do
  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day +  # starting from today
    rand(21).days +                # pick a random day, no further than 3 weeks out
    rand(24).hours +               # move forward to a random hour on that day
    (rand(2) * 30).minutes         # and then decide whether to add 30 minutes
end
```

or, could combine the hours + minutes

```
date_range = 6.times.collect do
  DateTime.now.beginning_of_day +  # starting from today
    rand(21).days +                # pick a random day, no further than 3 weeks out
    (rand(48) * 30).minutes        # pick a random interval of 30 minutes to add in
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the working solution but not complete:

```
6.times { date_range << DateTime.parse((DateTime.now + (rand * 21)).beginning_of_hour.to_s) }

[Mon, 31 Jul 2017 06:00:00 +0530,
 Thu, 03 Aug 2017 15:00:00 +0530,
 Fri, 11 Aug 2017 14:00:00 +0530,
 Mon, 31 Jul 2017 09:00:00 +0530,
 Wed, 09 Aug 2017 16:00:00 +0530,
 Sat, 12 Aug 2017 13:00:00 +0530]
```

This can work for now but need some datetime with 30 minutes as well.